# Math : How to convert a 3D World to 2D Screen coordinate

Tags: c#, math, coordinate-systems

I'm looking for a way to convert 3D xyz coordinates to 2D xy (pixel) coordinates. I'm getting a list of coordinates which I need to plot on a 2d plane.

The plane will always be a top-down view width the following dimensions width:800 px, height 400px

The 3D world coordinates can contain negative values aswell ranging from -4000 to 4000. I have read a few conversion articles on Wikipedia and a couple of SO threads but they either didn't fit my needs or they were too complex for my limited math knowledge.

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you for your time.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Do you want it converted preserving the scale, i.e. for something like  engineering drawings where distance matters, or using perspective, i.e. objects farther away appear smaller, closer ones appear bigger?

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like [(x/z),(y/z)] to project 3d to 2d - I believe this is a fairly crude method and I would think that 3d to 2d Googlings would return some fairly standard algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Rob is more or less correct, just that normally a scaling factor needs to be used (i.e [k*(x/z), k*(y/z)]). If you never change your point or direction of view, all the math you need to fully understand why this works are the intercept theorems.

I think the standard implementation of this uses so-called homogenous coordinates, which is a bit more complicated. But for a quick-and-dirty implementation just using 'normal' 3D coordinates works fine.

You also need to be a bit careful when dealing with coordinates that are behind your point of view. In fact, this is what I have found the most ugly part of (polygon-based) 3D graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this interesting: [A 3D Plotting Library in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Plot3D.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Something that may help: Some code i'm working on...

```
// Location in 3D space (x,y,z), w = 1 used for affine matrix transformations...
public class Location3d : Vertex4d
{
    // Default constructor
    public Location3d()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.z = 0;
        this.w = 1; // w = 1 used for affine matrix transformations...
    }
    // Initiated constructor(dx,dy,dz)
    public Location3d(double dx, double dy, double dz)
    {
        this.x = dx;
        this.y = dy;
        this.z = dz;
        this.w = 1;     // w = 1 used for affine matrix transformations...
    }
}

// Point in 2d space(x,y) , screen coordinate system?
public class Point2d
{
    public int x { get; set; }              // 2D space x,y
    public int y { get; set; }

    // Default constructor
    public point2d()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
}

// Check if a normal  vertex4d of a plane is pointing away?
// z = looking toward the screen +1 to -1   
public bool Checkvisible(Vertex4d v)
{
    if(v.z <= 0)
    {
        return false;       // pointing away, thus invisible
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// Check if a vertex4d is behind you, out of view(behinde de camera?)
// z = looking toward the screen +1 to -1
public bool CheckIsInFront(Vertex4d v)
{
    if(v.z < 0)
    {
        return false;       // some distans from the camera
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Some clipping to be done if the vertecies are outside the screen area !!!